# Segmentation Fault (Core Dump) C

Tags: c

I've started to study C this week, I'm totally new in programming in C, and when I tryed to do this exercise this error in the console keep showing up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float calc(float *sall, float *salb)
{
    float hraula, insspc;
    int naula;
    printf("Digite o valor da hora-aula e o numero de aulas dadas:");
    scanf("%f%i", hraula, naula);
    printf("Digite a porcentagem do inss retirada do salário:");
    scanf("%f",insspc);
    *salb = hraula * naula;
    *sall = *salb * ((100 - insspc) / 100);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float salbt, sallq;
    calc(&sallq, &salbt);
    printf("O salário bruto é: %f R$, liquido: %f R$", salbt, sallq);
    return 0;
}
```

Well hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried step by step debugging your program?

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf(" %f%i", hraula, naula);
scanf(" %f",insspc);
```

It should be as scanf requires the pointers to variables:

```
scanf(" %f%i", &hraula, &naula);
scanf(" %f",&insspc);
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Comment: Note that the leading space is unnecessary here, since the `f` conversion specifier already skips leading whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a *pointer* to the receiving variables like this:

```
scanf("%f%i", &hraula, &naula);
```

Similarly

```
scanf("%f", &insspc);
```

Reference: [`man 3 scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

It is also good practice to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that you have collected the correct number of values. Something like this:

```
if (scanf("%f%i", &hraula, &naula) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read hraula and naula\n");
    return -1;
}
```

and then check the return value of `calc()`:

```
if (calc(&sallq, &salbt) == 0)
    printf("O salário bruto é: %f R$, liquido: %f R$", salbt, sallq);
```